# previous and present size of arraylist as condition

Tags: java, android, firebase, arraylist

I would like to know how can i create a condition in android studio based on the past size of array list and the present size of array list after I added a new data in the firebase realtime database.

Something like

```
if (previous array list != array list with new data added) {
     //code here
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a JSON file. You can simply get it by clicking the Export JSON in the overflow menu (⠇) in your [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/_/database/data) and please also indicate the exact query you want to perform.

Comment: Hello. I just want to know how to it can be done through coding. Like, the condition should work if there is a new data added to the current length of the array list, therefore changing it.

Comment: To be able to help, we need to see your database schema. Can you add it to your question?